# How to get only the most recent jmeter result summary?

Tags: jmeter

When i run the jmeter test scripts and save the results in a .jtl file,
all test results including the most recent results are always appended to the file.
How can i get only the results for the most recent test run?

Comment: Are you running your script in GUI mode or non-GUI mode?

Comment: I run my scripts on Non GUI mode

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to dump those reports to separate files with each run. For example you can do it by using [__time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function and adding date and time to the file name, so you can set filename as something like this:

```
${__time(dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss)}.jtl
```